# Конвертировать mp3 в wav c характеристиками 8 bit, 32kHz, mono

Tags: python-3.x

Недавно столкнулся со следующей проблемой: необходимо конвертировать mp3 файл в wav c характеристиками 8 bit, частота дискретизации 32kHz, моно. Использую python3.6. И хотелось бы обойтись использованием стандартных библиотек(или установленными) и стандартными Windows утилитами (программа только для windows).
Пробовал pydub, но у меня не получилось заставить его работать корректно, а также сложная установка ffmpeg. Моя функция audioConvert(inFileWay, outFileWay, sFreq = 32000) не меняла характеристики, просто меняла расширение. Кроме pydub не смог найти другие библиотеки, которые бы могли изменять необходимые параметры.

Comment: Но ведь установка ffmpeg совсем несложная, достаточно скачать архив и распаковать в удобное место

Comment: так pydub её не видел, необходимо было еще закидывать ее в системную папку. Тк я потом планирую закатать свою программу в exe, то такие танцы с бубном не очень удобны.

Comment: Нет необходимости использовать обёртки над ffmpeg, вы всегда можете использовать ffmpeg напрямую с помощью команд вроде `os.system('путь/к/ffmpeg.exe -i путь/к/файлу.mp3 -c:a pcm_u8 -ar 32000 -ac 1 путь/к/файлу.wav')`

Comment: Говорят, что при использовании pyinstaller этот ffmpeg [можно запаковать в exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57896125) (при запуске он автоматически распакуется во временную папку), но лично я не пробовал

Comment: Спасибо, команда работает. Но есть другая проблема если я запускаю эту команду "ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i 1.mp3 -c:a pcm_u8 -ar 32000 -ac 1 2.wav" в одной и той же директории через git bash все работает, но если через python или через командную строку, то выдает ошибку " "ffmpeg" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

Comment: Значит путь к ffmpeg относительно текущей папки неправильный прописали

Comment: Спасибо) Очень помогли